# iOS CI with Jenkins

Tags: ios, ruby, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup CI for iOS using Jenkins. I have all the plugins installed and these are my Build scripts. I followed the steps here: https://www.built.io/blog/2014/10/how-to-set-up-customized-jenkins-for-ios/

For environment variables:

I am injecting the variables using environment injector plugin:

```
 PROJECT_DIR_NAME=AppName-dir
 PROJECT_NAME=AppName-app
 IPA_PATH=${WORKSPACE}/ipa-dir/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}-${BUILD_ID}.ipa
 PROJFILENAME=${WORKSPACE}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj
 TARGET=${PROJECT_NAME}
 PROVPROFILE_UUID=moj.io Inc.
 INFOPLIST_FILE=${WORKSPACE}/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-Info.plist
```

The build script is:

```
projmodify ${PROJFILENAME} ${TARGET} "iPhone Distribution: CompanyName" ${PROVPROFILE_UUID}
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${BUILD_NUMBER}" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

This is giving me the error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zerg_xcode-0.5.0/lib/zerg_xcode/paths.rb:27:in `open': No such file or directory - /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/App_iOS_Build/workspace/AppName-app.xcodeproj (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zerg_xcode-0.5.0/lib/zerg_xcode/paths.rb:27:in `entries'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zerg_xcode-0.5.0/lib/zerg_xcode/paths.rb:27:in `project_file_at'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zerg_xcode-0.5.0/lib/zerg_xcode/shortcuts.rb:12:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/projmodify.rb:7:in `doctorProject'
    from /usr/bin/projmodify.rb:41:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong ?